# Loading rdara/rds file in Java using Renjin

Tags: java, r, renjin

I want to load & parse RDS/RData files in Java, i've made some googling and found that Renjin helps calling R functions in Java. (i'm not a R developer and i didn't even know the existance of these files before ^^')

so this is my R code :

```
my_data <- readRDS("R/outputs_profils_cl8.RDS")
```

and this is my Java code :

```
RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
RenjinScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
        
engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("R/script.R"));
```

my pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.renjin</groupId>
        <artifactId>renjin-script-engine</artifactId>
        <version>3.5-beta65</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i got this error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: cannot read
> workspace version 3 written by R 3.5.0; need R 3.5.0 or newer     at
> org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$unserializeFromConn.applyPromised(R$primitive$unserializeFromConn.java:42)
> at org.renjin.sexp.BuiltinFunction.apply(BuiltinFunction.java:100)
> at
> org.renjin.primitives.special.InternalFunction.apply(InternalFunction.java:46)
> at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)  at
> org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:39)
> at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)  at
> org.renjin.sexp.Closure.applyPromised(Closure.java:200)   at
> org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:133)   at
> org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)   at
> org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.assignLeft(AssignLeftFunction.java:58)
> at
> org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.apply(AssignLeftFunction.java:42)
> at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)  at
> org.renjin.sexp.ExpressionVector.eval(ExpressionVector.java:85)   at
> org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:280)    at
> org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:174)
> at
> org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:169)
> at
> org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:148)
> at control.Main.main(Main.java:330)

do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?
i've followed installation instructions from Renjin website.

and I remain open if you can propose any other solution/library that can do the work :)

Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure there are ways to do this, I think you should ask yourself if you *should*.

`.RData` is not a conventional format to store and transfer files between different software. Instead, you should export your data *from* the `.Rdata` files to a more suitable format, for example comma-separated values (`.csv`).

These others formats have much wider support, and will be much more suited in most cases.